# Error while running a basic wordcount program on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, installation

Let me inform you that I am a beginner in hadoop domain. So, I was referring to https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module3.html tutorial. I completed all the set up and just copied all the codes to my eclipse map-reduce project. No error is showing as far as wordcountmapper,wordcountreducer and wordcount.java files are concerned.

Now, when I click on run on hadoop and select the already set server on VM player and click next, nothing happens afterwards. The same "run on hadoop with the selected server page" stays like get stucked. A progress information panel comes for a very shorter span, so can't check what it says actually.

However, this is what I get at log files every time after completing all these steps. Please help me out. I am struggling with this since last 2 days. As far as required libraries go, I have added all the required .jar files from hadoop installation path.

.log file contents ---

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2015-05-31 16:56:39.849
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table cannot be cast to org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableColumn
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.getColumn(Table.java:766)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.releaseChildren(Table.java:1532)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:840)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:840)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:840)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:840)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:840)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:840)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:840)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.releaseChildren(Canvas.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.releaseChildren(Decorations.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.releaseChildren(Shell.java:932)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Widget.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.dispose(Decorations.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.dispose(Shell.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.close(Window.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.close(Dialog.java:971)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.TrayDialog.close(TrayDialog.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.hardClose(WizardDialog.java:797)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.close(WizardDialog.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.cancelPressed(WizardDialog.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog$1.widgetSelected(WizardDialog.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1006)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:2413)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:2164)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:796)
    at org.apache.hadoop.eclipse.launch.HadoopApplicationLaunchShortcut.findLaunchConfiguration(HadoopApplicationLaunchShortcut.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.JavaLaunchShortcut.launch(JavaLaunchShortcut.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.JavaLaunchShortcut.searchAndLaunch(JavaLaunchShortcut.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.JavaLaunchShortcut.launch(JavaLaunchShortcut.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchShortcutExtension.launch(LaunchShortcutExtension.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.LaunchShortcutAction.run(LaunchShortcutAction.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1006)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:2413)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:2164)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2389)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2353)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2219)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$4.run(Workbench.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1173)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error doesn't seem to be related to hadoop. I couldn't find any reference to a SWT Table or column in that page also.

You could start a normal java application to see if everything it's working ok, and after that run wordcount ($HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples) from a terminal, to test your hadoop instalation. After that you should come back to eclipse to see if everything it's working (in hadoop there is always less problems running things from terminal instead of doing it directly from eclipse)